# История лайков на комментарии

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, комментарии

Просмотреть историю **своих** *отрицательных и положительных голосов* на вопросы и ответы (Активность -> голоса) - можно. А почему нет такой функции по отношению к комментариям?

А зачем? :

Да, комментарии бывают не всегда полезными, но к примеру мне понравился комментарий в плане информативности. Я ставлю этому комментарию голос, т.к информация для меня интересная. Проходит время. Хочу вспомнить какие комментарии я примечал. А функции такой нет, значит информация считай пропала. Можно конечно предложить автору комментария, чтобы он этот комментарий перенёс в секцию ответов, **но** :

1. Комментарий формата "предлагаю использовать это, вместо этого" - как ответ такое считать не айс.
2. Автор комментария захотел помочь, но ему лень описывать и приводить свой комментарий в состояние "Easy answer for everyone" <strike>Включая новичков</strike>.

и т.д и т.п. Думаю теперь ясно.

Comment: ........... зачем?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почему нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский зачем ёрничать? Вопрос нормальный. Есть список голосов за вопросы/ответы. Почему нету такого же для комментариев? К тому же, в старой версии SO Api такой метод был.

Comment: Комментарии являются вспомогательным инструментом (и вообще не поощряются), поэтому с ними связано меньше функциональности.

Comment: @Suvitruf мой логичный вопрос был "Зачем?". Каково практическое и конструктивное применение оного?

Comment: @Nofate не поощряются? Если мне память не изменяет, то за них даже баджики есть.

Comment: Комментарии удаляются/переносятся в чат. Всю важную информацию рекомендуется включать в вопрос/ответ. Тревоги на комментарии менее детально фиксируются.

Comment: @Suvitruf А то, что комментарии хотят убрать и переделать в `уточнение к вопросу` вы не в курсе? Это реально очень вспомогательный инструмент и это биг дата, Шиманский задаёт правильный вопрос "а зачем" эти данные ещё больше увеличивать за счёт хранения историчности?

Comment: @AK мой посыл был в том, что вместо ответа о том, почему это не надо, Алексей начал ёрничать. Если бы он сразу дал ответ, то ни одного комментария в этой ветке бы не было.

Comment: @Suvitruf нет, посыл неверен. Это **не я** или кто-то еще должен давать ответ почему это не надо, а нужно  в первую очередь **автору вопроса/предложения** (или вам, раз уж любите вопросом на вопрос) ответить на вопрос зачем это нужно. Собственно, при *предложении чего-либо* в первую очередь и обосновывается причина нужды в этом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский автор ничего не предлагал.

Comment: @Suvitruf стоит метка "Предложение". Значит он хочет что-то предложить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не тащите сюда школьный сленг вроде «лайк» и «диз».

Comment: btw, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/pundit Этот бадж даже а выборах модератора учитывается.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подобное предложение уже было озвучено более пяти лет назад на MSE и имеет следующий [ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148029/339911) (привожу краткий перевод со своими добавками):

Комментарии — это второстепенные сущности. Они являются временными объектами, это значит, кто когда цель, высказанная в комментарии, достигнута, комментарий следует удалить. В частности, с недавних пор изменился список флагов на комментариях, явно был выделен пункт, говорящий о том, что комментарий устарел и требует удаления:

> [image: не является необходимым]

Это приводит к тому, что любые предложения доработки функциональности по просмотру комментариев, которые вы отметили полезными, будут бесполезны! Такой вот каламбур.

При этом можно видеть голоса, отданные вопросам и ответам, а значит, достаточно проголосовать на сообщении, содержащим комментарий, чтобы потом иметь возможность его найти (конечно, при условии, что он не будет удалён к этому времени).